# Accessing elements of JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I'm having some trouble accessing model objects from my view model. This is likely just a JavaScript/KnockoutJS familiarity issue, so any help is appreciated. Here's my code:

```
<!-- VIEW -->
<select data-bind="options: allTypes, 
                   optionsCaption: 'Choose...',                   
                   value: chosenType"></select>
<div data-bind="text: chosenType"></div>
<div data-bind="text: chosenValues"></div> <!-- << This line not working -->
<script type="text/javascript">

/*-- VIEW MODEL --*/
function ViewModel() {
    this.chosenType=ko.observable();
    this.chosenValues=allValues[this.chosenType]; // <-- Problem here?
}

/*-- MODEL --*/
var allTypes=["Animals","Plants","Minerals"];
var allValues={
    "Animals":["Pig","Big pig","Owl"],
    "Plants":["Aloe","Fern"],
    "Minerals":["Bauxite","Chromite"]
    };

    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
</script>
```

I think the problem is likely in how this.chosenValues is being declared. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Is there some reason you aren't providing an argument to `ko.observable()`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. There's no argument to `ko.observable` because `this.chosenType` doesn't need a default value, and I think that part's working OK.

Comment: Can you inspect `new ViewModel()`? Is `viewModel.chosenValues` returning undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>The **text** binding is for single values only, not collections/arrays.</strike> 
You can use the **foreach** binding to list each item i.e.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: chosenValues">
    <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
</div>
```

Or you can use a computedObservable i.e.

```
function ViewModel() {
   this.chosenType=ko.observable();
   // computed value is evaluated if an observable value changes
   // this creates a comma separated string of values
   // you'll probably want safety checks here but just a quick sample
   this.chosenValues=ko.computed(function() {
        var chosenVals=allValues[this.chosenType()];
        return chosenVals.join(', ');
   }, this);
}
```

Also remember to update the UI from a model, you will need some form of observable.  In your example **chosenValues** is not an observable so will not update the UI if a selection changes.

Also see https://jsfiddle.net/51oufny4/ for a working sample

**Edit** **
Here is the sample provided in the above fiddle:

```
<!-- VIEW -->
<select data-bind="options: allTypes, 
               optionsCaption: 'Choose...',                   
               value: chosenType"></select>
<div data-bind="text: chosenType"></div>
<div data-bind="text: chosenValues"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

/*-- VIEW MODEL --*/
function ViewModel() {
    this.chosenType=ko.observable();
    this.chosenValues=ko.computed(function(){
        return allValues[this.chosenType()];
    }, this);
}

/*-- MODEL --*/
var allTypes=["Animals","Plants","Minerals"];
var allValues={
    "Animals":["Pig","Big pig","Owl"],
    "Plants":["Aloe","Fern"],
    "Minerals":["Bauxite","Chromite"]
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
</script>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this! I swapped in the `foreach` code and made `this.chosenValues` an observable: `this.chosenValues=ko.observable(allValues[this.chosenType]);` No luck yet. Am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like I partially lied (my apologies).  Looks like the text binding automatically creates a comma separated string.  You're forgetting to evaluate your observable chosenType.  Remember chosenType is an observable and you need to unwrap to get the underlying value. See my fiddle here:  https://jsfiddle.net/51oufny4/

Comment: The fiddle works great, thanks! If you want to update this answer with the working code from the fiddle, I'll mark it as accepted.